# itext pdfstamper makes the document read only

Tags: itext

I'm reading in a PDF document with fillable fields, and using PdfStamper to fill in the form, the output of from the stamper is a read only PDF, how can make it output a PDF document with the fields filled but still fillable?

Comment: No code sample is provided; we are expected to guess what the OP did wrong.

Comment: With that description we can only say: you do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `setFormFlattening(true)`? If so, then the behavior is normal. Change `true` to `false` and the form will remain "fillable". Learn about the difference by reading my answer to this question: [iText How to create multi-page document from a fillable template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185830)

This is the most likely reason why your form is no longer interactive: you are removing all the interactivity by flattening the form. (If that's not the case, please share your code so that we can see what is going on.)

Or... is your PDF reader-enabled? If so, use `PdfStamper` in append mode. Maybe you're experiencing the problem explained in the question [Why do I get an error saying that "use of extended features is no longer available"?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-do-i-get-error-saying-use-extended-features-no-longer-available)